# Completely Block Software From Internet

Tags: networking, firewall

I am trying to block software from connecting to the internet.
I have a backup image of my PC with it all working offline, but as soon as I connect it to the internet, the software connects.

It does this without opening/running the software, I think it has a background service or something that goes out on its own?

I have looked to try and see what is doing it to no avail, tried Glasswire to block it connecting but it still does it.

Can I find out the IP its connecting to and block that?

Comment: You're using windows?

Comment: Yes I'm on windows 10

Comment: Unplug the Ethernet cable?

Comment: I believe the built-in firewall can block by application?

Answer (score 0):

It obviously has a service installed that accesses the internet.  Since you're having trouble identifying it it's probably named something unlike the main program.

On XP and Windows 7 I would block such things by figuring out the URL and routing that URL to 127.0.0.1 with the hosts file.  I would think that could also be done on Windows 10 but I have never tried to do so.

(And for those who think that such blocking can only be for piracy uses--I've done it more than once to get a program to shut up about offering an update I don't want and I've done it once because the scumbags decided to include some ads in a paid program.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any idea how I can track down where its going to?

Comment: Beast: Wireshark.  Start the fresh image offline, start wireshark logging, connect the computer, wait for it to communicate successfully, stop the wireshark logging, and examine the log for traffic that might be associated with the program.

Comment: Thanks! Ill give that a go. Hopefully I can sort it.